# How to get inner padding (or a gap) between each grouped bar in a Bar Chart in Recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am trying to achieve a similar effect to Inner Padding that Nivo Charts uses, but in Recharts.

I have the following bar:

[image]

but I want to have it look more like this one (not in terms of colour, but in terms of the gap between the two bars):
[image]

The difference is slight but there is a white gap separating the 2 colours. How do I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve this effect by adding
`style={{ stroke: '#fff', strokeWidth: 2 }}` to `<BarChart>`:

```
<BarChart
  layout="vertical"
  data={barChartData}
  height={300}
  barSize={24}
  barCategoryGap={16}
  style={{ stroke: '#fff', strokeWidth: 2 }}
>
```

If you were to add empty `<Bar />` data to achieve this, you might encounter some weirdness once you start using Tooltips on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any padding solution, so I found a workaround using an extra bar between the two existing bars, and set it to a given constant, with the color 'white'.

I assumed you used the BarChart, so here is what it would look like with it:

```js
const {BarChart, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend} = Recharts;

// First, add the fake data ('blank' in this example)
// with a given constant (here, I chose 50)
const data = [
    {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, blank: 50, amt: 2400},
    [...]
];
const StackedBarChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
    return (
        <BarChart width={600} height={300} data={data} barGap={'70%'}
            margin={{top: 20, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis/>
       <Tooltip/>
       <Legend />
       <Bar dataKey="pv" stackId="a" fill="#8884d8" />
       // Add a additional Bar containing the fake data, filled in white
       <Bar dataKey="blank" stackId="a" fill="#fff" />
       <Bar dataKey="uv" stackId="a" fill="#82ca9d" />
      </BarChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <StackedBarChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Here is the fiddle to see the final result: https://jsfiddle.net/utvzxhfd/2/

It's probably not the most elegant solution, but it outputs the desired effect!